# Opening a stored procedure file multiple times in sql server management studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

In Sql Server Management Studio, there is strange situation that made me lose a full day work. It is the problem of opening database objects multiple times. When I try to edit a table by right clicking from the object explorer, it is opening the edit screen for the first time, at second time it is re-opening the previously opened but not in a new edit screen. Despite that, if I try to select from that table by right clicking from the object explorer, it is opening the new query with the select statement multiple times while I retry this process. It is also doing exactly the same thing for the stored procedures and functions. I lost my changes in a stored procedure because of opening multiple times.In Visual Studio it is not possible to re-open a file in new editor multiple times by default. Are there any option to reconfigure sql server management studio to not open an object which is already opened in editor?
Note: I know this is my problem to remember which objects I have already opened, but I am asking for help, if there is an option that I am not aware.
Note #2: I have doubt that, this is the right place to ask such question. Please do not offend me.

Comment: I agree with you that this might be a usability problem. It deviates from the usual concept of "files", because internally, the "Modify" option on a view or a procedure is functionally equivalent to "script stored procedure as > ALTER to > new query window". So what you really do is open a new query window (an "unnamed file") and paste some script into it. As users of SSMS, we have to be aware of that. Consider using source control to prevent data loss.

Comment: I suggest you ask this question on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: This is how we do it: We have all our sprocs stored in files (one file per sproc). To edit the sproc you double click the file instead of the object in SQL server. The files are checked into git (you could use any source control system) . At deploy we run the sproc scripts using https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse

Comment: @mortb it seems like a good solution but it is not what I am looking for. thank you.

Comment: you have a problem which is part of process you choose. choose a better process, maybe the one mortb suggested.

Comment: @AlicanUzun: Well, I've had the same problem that you are experiencing. I can feel your pain :) I don't think that you can get management studio to do what you want. The setup that we currently use is the one that have caused the least pain for me.

Comment: @mortb I bookmarked 'roundhouse', so I will try it in the closest future :)

Comment: Alican, as others have mentioned, this is the difference between a solution and a series of files.  SSMS allows us the creation and use of projects in a similar manner to VS, and this is the way I tend to go when making changes to my databases. Open SSMS: Create a new project. Once created you can add connections to it, and also queries. When making any changing to a DB object, make sure there is a query for this in your project, just one for each object, which you can execute to change the object. In this way you have the latest version of the object code each time.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is, no. Unfortunately there is no option to prevent such thing happening. Not even in SSMS16. SSMS does not work like opening a file. Every time you modify a stored procedure, or generate a script for a table, it is basically (like I said) generating the script for that database object. Same goes for all the tables, stored procedures, views and functions. So I guess you'll need to pay a bit more attention for not to lose your work :-)